# Sprite[] in an Array[] isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my current Unity Project I have a Script with an `Array[]` and I want to add to this `Array[1]` a `Sprite[]`.

Is this possible?

This is a part of my code:

```
Array[] ObjectTypestobuy;
public Sprite[] Characters;

public Button[] ObjectButtons;

//...

ObjectTypestobuy[1] = Characters; //Start Method

//...
ObjectButtons[index].transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ObjectTypestobuy[currenttab[1]]; //this line of code isn't working. it shows an error at 'currenttab[1]'
```

Do you know how to solve this? Are there other ways?

***Update:***

After working at this problem I get solution. But it's not working. I tried to make a `public Sprite[][] ObjectTypestobuy;` and than I wrote this code in my Start-function:

```
        ObjectTypestobuy[0] = Characters;
        ObjectTypestobuy[1] = Helmets;
        ObjectTypestobuy[2] = Weapons;
        ObjectTypestobuy[3] = Mantles;
        ObjectTypestobuy[4] = Shields;

//..............................................
```

This is the code over Start-function:

```
    public Sprite[][] ObjectTypestobuy;

    public Sprite[] Characters; 
    public Sprite[] Helmets;
    public Sprite[] Weapons;
    public Sprite[] Mantles;
    public Sprite[] Shields;
```

And then I wanted to get this line of code working:

```
ObjectButtons[index].transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ObjectTypestobuy[currenttab][index]; // index is an integer
```

...but it sadly didn't work :(

Comment: Array class is abstract. you should initialize it. some thing like :                      Array[] ObjectTypestobuy = new string[5];

Comment: I think this isn't working for me :(        ...any other ways?

Comment: That is creating an array of `Array`s. If you can't use an actual `Sprite[]` then you could use `Arraylist` but it is generally discouraged because of it's lack of type safety.

Comment: If your actual issue is an error with `currenttab[1]`, what is `currenttab`?

Comment: 'currenttab' is just a simple 'int'. Could be for example 'ObjectTypestobuy[1[1]];'

Comment: How is ObjectButtons declared?

Comment: "... but it sadly didn't work" don't say it didn't work, say what are you expecting, what error did you get, what did you already do for trying to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is an abstract class so you can't initialize it directly (unless you implement it inline). If you want to store collections of sprites and use them like that you can simply use the good old List.
Example:

```
List<Sprite[]> objectTypestobuy = new List<Sprite[]>();
```

This approach is much more simple and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sprite[,] ObjectTypestobuy
```

If you want all the arrays to have the same length. Or:

```
Sprite[][] ObjectTypestobuy
```

If you want arrays of different size on each line.

You can fetch values by:

```
ObjectTypestobuy[I, j]
```

On the first case or:

```
ObjectTypestobuy[i][j]
```

In the second case.

Comment: Why downvote? multidimensional array in c# / Unity are in fact declared with `[,]`.

Comment: I was asking myself the same. Lists as fields are not as idiomatic in Unity as arrays, at all.

Comment: @Jul so, did you apply this suggestion? Did this answer help you? If yes, you can mark this as "accepted", so it'll be easier for other people with the same issue to find the solution.